# Licensing specification

Tags: open-source, licensing, standards, specifications

I'm making open specification and I want people to be able implement specification for commercial and open source purposes. But I want to control all modifications to specification, so all modifications to specification itsef must be prohibited. What kind of license I can use for this specification?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creative Commons +Attribution +NoDerivs?

> This license allows for
>   redistribution, commercial and
>   non-commercial, as long as it is
>   passed along unchanged and in whole,
>   with credit to you.

See http://creativecommons.org/licenses/.